# Is that valid to write page method in user control?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a web application using .net/c#. I have a user control that I want to call it's page methhod from client side by using javascript. However, I found the page method could be called if I put it in parent page, but can not if I put the method in user control code file. But for some reasons, I have no control on parent page, but have fullly control on user control. How to overcome this limitation?

I call pagemethod using javascript like this:

```
jQuery("[id$='tb_UserName']").blur(function() {
var login = jQuery("[id$='tb_UserName']").val();
    PageMethods.SearchUserName(login, SearchUserNameCallback);
});
function SearchUserNameCallback(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

The Page method SearchUserName is defined as following:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SearchUserName(string name)
{
    ...
}
```

The method has no problem, just it's location make a big difference. If I put it in user control code file, error comes out as "Pagemethods is undefined." If I put it in parent code file, it works fine. But I have no control on parent file, I can only do it in my test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a **Page** Method because they only exist at the page level.  If you need something that can exist in different scopes, you should use a ASMX or WCF webservice and include them as a ServiceReference in your ScriptManager.

Comment: Is that possible to call web service from user control?

Comment: Yes you can call them from anywhere.  There is a special ScriptManagerProxy control that you can use to "extend" a script manager from a component higher up in the page hiearchy (ie: ScriptManager on MasterPage, ScriptManagerProxy on page/user control)